# In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required error

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def hug(ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):

    hug_embed = discord.Embed(title='-w- hug -w-', description='', color=0xafe8fa)
    hug_embed.add_field(name=f'{ctx.author.mention} hugged {user.mention}', value='', inline=False)

    if user:
        await ctx.message.channel.send(embed=hug_embed)
    else:
        await ctx.send('hug someone ;n;')
```

I got the error of
`In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required`

how do i mention another person, with it sending in an embed response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests you need to put something in the value of the field. Right now you have `''`, try with `'something else'`

Comment: Also you could use `"\u200b"` which is an empty line